# Relation or document-oriented database will fit more

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, compare, database

I'm building a project when a user can select multiple items and add them to sets, which he can share. Till now the database looks like this:

[image]

I've started thinking to switch it to MongoDB with the following structure:

```
    Sets Collection:
    {
            _id: ObjectId("51e06e788abe12d1070352351"), 
            name: "somename", //name of the set
            uid: "df4naL3_", // shortID for the URL
            createdby: ObjectId("51e06e788abe12d107000001"), //mongoId of the user
            items: {
                    [{
                            _id: ObjectId("51e06e788abe12d1070352351"),
                            category: "Dress",
                            title: "some title",
                            price: "33",
                            image: "someimage.png",
                            buyLink: "http://"
                    }]
            }
    }



    Items Collection:
    {
            _id: ObjectId("51e06e788abe12d1070352351"),
            category: "Dress",
            title: "some title",
            price: "33",
            image: "someimage.png",
            buyLink: "http://"
    }
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a point of switching to MongoDB, or Mysql will fit my needs better for this project and why?
2. Since MongoDB doesn't support joins, what will be the solution to implement item categories? Note that the items will be indexed by categories and the categories title will look like: "Accessoaries".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Here's a great post on NoSQL DB-design.](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/.)
2. One of the implications of NoSQL is that de-normalization is okay.  You're optimizing for retrieval speed at the expense of storage space.  So, you could make duplicates of all your items and insert them as a sub-array of your sets instances.  OR, you could just insert references in a sub-array on your Set instances.  This would then require 2 queries (1 to fetch the list of ids, and another to fetch all the items matching those ides.

When we move out of relational database into the NoSQL world, this idea of data duplication feels really uncomfortable.  It's perfectly acceptable in NoSQL though, because you're just optimizing for something different.  And yes, if you ever deleted an instance from Items, you'd need to delete the copies from any instance of Sets that has them.

The question boils down to how your application will access the data.  If you're frequently accessing the container and all the details about its contents, then NoSQL might just be a good fit here.

Honestly though, your end users likely won't care, and at the loads that most applications have, you probably wouldn't notice the difference in execution speed.  My recommendation is use what you're familiar with until load and usage dictates that you start optimizing.  That's one of the proverbial Good Problems To Have.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I just want to ask 1-2 questions to make the things clear for me. I'm more familiar with MongoDB, but If I use the following structure I mentioned, a lot of sets will have dublicate data. Won't this architecture take much storage space?

Comment: You're right that it will, but that's not a no-no in NoSQL design like it is in relational design.  It would put more of a responsibility on you to deal with updating duplicate records, and certainly if space is a concern, then you can model it just by storing references.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience relational dbs are the best choice for most solution. They are mature, their query syntax is intuitive and there are a lot of tools you can use with them to speed up your developement process and make sure your solution is robust. One should have good reasons to consider a NoSQL db. This is no that I don't like NoSQL, I really do and I'm using it when it's required. The most common reasons for it is complex data schema, performance, etc. Why did you start considering NoSQL for your project? The answer to this question is also the answer to the questions you posted here. I suggest googling "When to use mongo". To me NoSQL isnot a tool by default it's more a tool to solve a specific problem.

Regarding your post:

1. There's no point to use MongoDB if you don't benefit from it more
   than from MySQL and I'm pretty sure you don't, taking into account
   your example. Your schema is simple and easily mapped to relational
   one and I don't think you are going to have any performance issues
   here. And what's is more important here is your experience with relational dbs.
2. For joins you will have either to denormalize your data or to query
   it separately.